# Pass data from InfoPath Web Part to HTML Web Part in SharePoint

Tags: html, sharepoint, submit, infopath

I have some text fields in a HTML Web Part and would like to pass whatever was submitted from an InfoPath web part to the fields in the HTML Web Part. This is so I can capture the data that is being submitted and do some calculations with it, before its submitted to the connected SharePoint List.

Can this be done?